# java regex to capture any number of periods within a string

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match on any of the following:

```
$tag:parent.child$
$tag:grand.parent.child$
$tag:great.grand.parent.child$
```

I have tried a bunch of combos but not sure how to do this without an exp for each one: https://regex101.com/r/cMvx9I/1

```
\$tag:[a-z]*\.[a-z]*\$
```

I know this is wrong, but haven't been able to find the right method yet. Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to replace the dots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\$tag:(?:[a-z]+\.)*[a-z]+\$`

- `\$` a literal $
- `tag:` literal tag:
- `(?:...)` a non-capturing group of:

  - `[a-z]+` one or more lower-case letters and
  - `\.` a literal dot
- `*` any number of the previous group (including zero of them)
- `[a-z]+` one or more lower-case letters
- `\$` a literal $

Comment: thanks very much, greatly appreciated. needed to learn group of.

Answer (score 3):

Your regex was: `\$tag:[a-z]*\.[a-z]*\$`

You need a repeating group of `.name`, so use: `\$tag:[a-z]+(?:\.[a-z]+)+\$`

That assumes there has to be at least 2 names. If only one name is allowed, i.e. no period, then change last `+` to `*`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, but you can make a non-capturing group out of a pattern and then find that a certain number of times:

```
\$tag:(?:[a-z]+?\.*){1,4}\$
```

- `\$tag:` - Literal $tag:
- `(?:[a-z]+?\.*)` - Non-capturing group of any word character one or more times (shortest match) followed by an optional literal period
- `{1,4}` - The capturing group appears anywhere between 1-4 times (you can change this as needed, or use a simple `+` if it could be any number of times).
- `\$` - Literal $

I normally prefer `\w` instead of `[a-z]` as it is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, but using this depends on what you are trying to find.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You don't need a capturing group. `\w` is different that what OP had.

Comment: Yes I find that `\w` is cleaner to use. It obviously depends on what is needed--if numbers and uppercase are not acceptable then `\w` would not be correct. Capturing group is to enable finding the pattern multiple times.

Comment: Or digits. Seems clear that OP doesn't want digits.

Comment: @user11809641 a non-capturing group also enables finding the pattern multiple times, without capturing

Comment: @DavidConrad Good Point! I changed my answer above.

Comment: @DavidConrad *FYI:* Using a *capturing* group doesn't prevent finding the pattern multiple times, but it would only capture the last time the pattern matched. E.g. pattern `^(.)*$` would match input string `ABC`, and `group()` would return `ABC`, while `group(1)` would return `C`, i.e. the capturing group only captured the last time `.` matched.

Comment: @Andreas the point is using a capturing group is completely unnecessary here.

Comment: @DavidConrad Yeah, but your comment made it sound like finding the pattern multiple times only works for non-capturing groups, and that's not correct.

Comment: @Andreas Well, that's not what I said. I said you don't ***need*** a capturing group, and I **meant** that you don't ***need*** a capturing group. A non-capturing group *also enables* finding the pattern multiple times. I think that's pretty clear.

Comment: @DavidConrad *"also enables"* implies that without using a non-capturing group, it isn't enabled. That is what I was trying to point out, that your comment can be misleading. I wanted to ensure that anyone reading the comment wouldn't mistakenly think that capturing groups couldn't find the pattern multiple times, while at the same time mentioning the quirk of how that actually works, to help *teach* people who didn't already know.

Comment: @Andreas No, ***also*** implies that they are both able to do that. If I can go to the store, and you can *also* go to the store, that does **not** imply that I **cannot** go to the store. I feel like you are working very hard here to interpret my words to mean something completely diametrically opposite to what I said.

Comment: @Andreas How could any reasonable reader interpret my sentence "You don't need a capturing group." to mean that a capturing group would not work?

Comment: @DavidConrad Not working hard at all, since that was my very first thought when I read your comment. And be aware that the comment saying *"also enables"* does not in any way say that you don't need a capturing group. Try reading the comment by itself, like most people would, not as a continuation of your first comment. Then consider *why* you would even mention that a non-capturing group *also enables* finding the pattern multiple times, unless it's because you're pointing out that in *addition* to being non-capturing, it *also* changes the behavior to allow finding the pattern multiple times

Answer (score 0):

The following pattern will match any periods within a string:

`\.`