# How to capture all instances with regex from a string with

Tags: java, regex

I got help with a regex expression in java here: [java regex to capture any number of periods within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59327752/java-regex-to-capture-any-number-of-periods-within-a-string)

This solved the issue of identifying patterns of the string, but I have been unable to figure out how to catch all instances within a body of text.

If I have a string body like this:

```
String body = "$tag:parent$ is the child of $tag:grand.parent$ who is the grandparent of $tag:child$"
```

I use the following and always catch the first $tag:*$ string, no matter which one is first the pattern gets it but within something like

```
final String REGEX = "\\$tag:(?:[a-z]+?\\.*){1,4}\\$";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
Matcher matcher = pt.matcher(body);
if (matcher.find()) {
    // do something with matcher.group()  but should the group contain the all instances?
}
```

I have tried enclosing in () on regex101.com and it matches patterns and lists everything in a group but this doesn't work

tried the following, but this is me just trying random stuff:

```
"(\\$tag:(?:[a-z]+?\\.*){1,4}\\$)"
"(^\\$tag:(?:[a-z]+?\\.*){1,4}\\$)"
"(?<=(\\$tag:(?:[a-z]+?\\.*){1,4}\\$))"
```

I just basically want a java regex approach where I catch all the instances in some type of manner. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Assuming your pattern is correct, why don't you just use a `while` loop instead of `if`? This way the matcher will iterate over all matched strings.

Comment: wow, talk about an obvious solution. this is correct/the answer. appreciate you pointing that out

Comment: Good to hear :) Happy matching!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elaborating on my comment:

Use a `while` loop to iterate over all matched patterns in your input, e.g.:

```
// note: I have simplified your pattern a bit, you probably don't need all 
// those restrictions
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\$tag:.+?\\$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(body);
while (matcher.find()) {
    // TODO whatever you want with the matched group
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

**Output**

```
$tag:parent$
$tag:grand.parent$
$tag:child$
```

Comment: yep, this was it, i just missed that right in front of me. appreciate you taking the time though.

Comment: @Justin no problem. In hindsight, note that you can also use "lookarounds" to avoid integrating the `$`s in your matched group (or even the `tag:` for that matter). **Edit**: or use a back-reference on the `.+?` part and reference it as `group(1)`.